# Problems selecting checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems using following method to select all checkboxes.

I'm using this example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
```

HTML

```
  <input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />

   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3
```

But the button fades out when entering the web page in jQuery 1.11.

What would be a fix for this?

Comment: FYI the toggle event was removed in jQuery 1.9. See http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: it is fading because you are calling toggle on the button on page load...this will make it `display: none;` on page load.

Answer (score 2):

This use of [toggle() was removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)... so you may have to use [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) if you are using jQuery >= 1.9 like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.check:button').click(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.value == 'check all');
        $(this).val(function () {
            return this.value == 'check all' ? 'uncheck all' : 'check all';
        })
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F23qx/)

Answer (score 2):

FYI the toggle event was removed in jQuery 1.9. See [api.jquery.com/toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event). Instead, try:

```
var checked = false;
$('.check:button').click(function () {
    checked = !checked;
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
    $(this).val(checked ? 'uncheck all' : 'check all')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xZSt4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('.check:button').click(function(){
   if($('input:checkbox:checked').length!=$('input:checkbox').length){
      $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
      $(this).val('uncheck all');
   }else{
      $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
      $(this).val('check all');                  
   }});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JJ9XR/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop` and modify your jquery code to the below. Though this use `click` event

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.check:button').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "check all") {
            $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            $(this).val('uncheck all');
        } else {
            $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).val('check all');
        }

    });
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/JJ9XR/1/